# Compared two dataframes on strings. I would like to assign the matched strings to one of the dataframes in the right column and row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    for country in df1['country ']:
        for street,City in zip(df2.street, df2.City):
            if re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+\:'+ street + r'\.'+ City,country ):
                s = (re.match(r'[A-Za-z]+\:'+ street + r'\.'+ TR + 
                     r'\_(VS).+',country))
                     Matches += 1
                     print(s)
             
    print(Matches)
```

df1:

```
     UID country  
 0    1  Gervais Philippon:France.PARISPenthièvre25
 1    2  Jed Turner:England.LONDONQueensway69 
 2    3  Lino Jimenez:Spain.MADRIDChavela33
```

df2:

```
    UID   country   City  
0    1    France    PARIS 
1    2    Spain     MADRID 
2    3    England   LONDON
```

Expected output:

```
     UID  country                                      UID_df2
0    1    Gervais Philippon:France.PARISPenthièvre25   1
1    2    Jed Turner:England.LONDONQueensway69         3
2    3    Lino Jimenez:Spain.MADRIDChavela33           2
```

The matches are shown correctly. How can i link the dataframes by assigning the matched string to the other dataframe ? I would like the ideal format:

Thank you.

Comment: please show both df and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

First I would renamed `country` in df1 to `data` or something else so it doesn't get confused with `country` in df2

`df1 = df1.rename(columns={'country': 'data'})`

Get the country and City data

`df1[['country', 'City']] = df1['data'].str.extract('(:([A-Z]+[a-z]*)).([A-Z]+)', expand=True)[[1, 2]]`

Fix the regex in the City name, this step can be removed by updating the regex above

`df1['City'] = df1['City'].map(lambda x: x[:-1])`

Finally merge with df2

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['country', 'City'])

   UID_x                                       place  country    City  UID_y
0      1  Gervais Philippon:France.PARISPenthièvre25   France   PARIS      1
1      2        Jed Turner:England.LONDONQueensway69  England  LONDON      3
2      3          Lino Jimenez:Spain.MADRIDChavela33    Spain  MADRID      2
```